# Python - subprocess.Popen breaks my brain over and over again

Tags: python, subprocess, telethon

I have a task to create a launcher for my telegram bot and userbot in parralel, and let their logs be in the same terminal. So my logic is: create 4 threads: one for bot, second for userbot, and the last two for functions which are supposed to spectrate first two processes and do some stuff if bot died. So, there is my code:

```
import datetime
import os
import subprocess
import time


def botwaiter(process_object):
    bot_alive = True
    while bot_alive:
        time.sleep(1)
        check = process_object.poll()
        if check == None:
            pass
        else:
            bot_alive = False
    print(f'[BotWaiter]-[{datetime.datetime.now()}] Main bot process has been terminated, checking files...')
    if os.path.exists('stopping'):
        print(f'[BotWaiter]-[{datetime.datetime.now()}] Bot has stopped due to stop request, doing nothing...')
        os.remove('stopping')
        return
    elif os.path.exists('updating'):
        print(f'[BotWaiter]-[{datetime.datetime.now()}] Bot has stopped due to update request, updating...')
        update_process = subprocess.run("git pull", shell=True, text=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        if update_process.stderr is not None:
            update_process = subprocess.run("git stash && git pull", shell=True, text=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
            print(f'[BotWaiter]-[{datetime.datetime.now()}] Update complete, starting back...')
            os.remove('updating')
            main('bot')
        else:
            print(f'[BotWaiter]-[{datetime.datetime.now()}] Update complete, starting back...')
            os.remove('updating')
            main('bot')
    elif os.path.exists('updatingdb'):
        print(f'[BotWaiter]-[{datetime.datetime.now()}] Bot has stopped due to update database request, updating...')
        update_process = subprocess.run("git commit main.dm -m \"Updated DB from Termux.\"", shell=True, text=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        if update_process.stderr is not None:
            print('Updating DB ended with error, cannot continue!\nError code:' + update_process.stderr)
            os.remove('updatingdb')
            return
        else:
            os.remove('updatingdb')
            main('bot')
    else:
        print(f'[BotWaiter]-[{datetime.datetime.now()}] Bot has stopped due to unknown reason, restarting...')
        time.sleep(1)
        main('bot')

def userbotwaiter(process_object):
    bot_alive = True
    while bot_alive:
        time.sleep(1)
        check = process_object.poll()
        if check == None:
            pass
        else:
            bot_alive = False
    print(f'[UserbotWaiter]-[{datetime.datetime.now()}] Main userbot process has been terminated, checking files...')
    if os.path.exists('ubstop'):
        print(f'[UserbotWaiter]-[{datetime.datetime.now()}] Userbot has stopped due to stop request, doing nothing...')
        os.remove('ubstop')
        return
    else:
        print(f'[UserbotWaiter]-[{datetime.datetime.now()}] Userbot has stopped due to unknown reason, restarting...')
        time.sleep(1)
        main('userbot')

def main(object_to_run = 'all'):
    try:
        if object_to_run == 'bot':
            print(f'[MainThread]-[{datetime.datetime.now()}] Starting bot...')
            bot_process = subprocess.Popen('python3 bot.py', shell=True)
            subprocess.Popen(botwaiter(bot_process))
            print(f'[MainThread]-[{datetime.datetime.now()}] Started bot!')
        elif object_to_run == 'userbot':
            print(f'[MainThread]-[{datetime.datetime.now()}] Starting userbot...')
            userbot_process = subprocess.Popen('python3 userbot.py', shell=True)
            subprocess.Popen(userbotwaiter(userbot_process))
            print(f'[MainThread]-[{datetime.datetime.now()}] Started userbot!')
        else:
            print(f'[MainThread]-[{datetime.datetime.now()}] Starting bot...')
            bot_process = subprocess.Popen('python3 bot.py', shell=True)
            subprocess.Popen(botwaiter(bot_process))
            print(f'[MainThread]-[{datetime.datetime.now()}] Started bot!')
            print(f'[MainThread]-[{datetime.datetime.now()}] Starting userbot...')
            userbot_process = subprocess.Popen('python3 userbot.py', shell=True)
            subprocess.Popen(userbotwaiter(userbot_process))
            print(f'[MainThread]-[{datetime.datetime.now()}] Started userbot!')
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print(f'[BotWaiter]-[{datetime.datetime.now()}] Catched Ctrl+C, stopping...')
        try:
            bot_process.kill()
            print(f'[BotWaiter]-[{datetime.datetime.now()}] Bot has been killed successfully')
        except:
            print(f'[BotWaiter]-[{datetime.datetime.now()}] Error while killing bot, please use pkill python3')
        try:
            userbot_process.kill()
            print(f'[BotWaiter]-[{datetime.datetime.now()}] Userbot has been killed successfully')
        except:
            print(f'[BotWaiter]-[{datetime.datetime.now()}] Error while killing userbot, please use pkill python3')
        exit()
os.system('clear')
main()
```

Aaaand, it breaks all my logic! It seems like it freezes at 81st or 82nd line (because the userbot is offline, and there is even no 83's line output!) *(81st line is main() func, else statement, line starts with "bot_process =")*, but the bot and botwaiter works fine... Until botwaiter needs to do some job. It just drops me this error after it's job:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 102, in <module>
    main()
  File "run.py", line 82, in main
    subprocess.Popen(botwaiter(bot_process))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 858, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1569, in _execute_child
    args = list(args)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Like it just decided to run 82nd line! Then how does the botwaiter work? And why doesn't that work properly? What is wrong?

Comment: `bot_process = subprocess.Popen('python3 bot.py', shell=True)` - why do you call other py script using Popen ?

Comment: Should I use multiprocessing/multithreading or something else instead? Sorry if that's a stupid question

Comment: Yes you should.

Comment: Okay then, I will try both. Thanks. But I'm still interested in why this code doesn't work as I planned :P

Comment: If you're using `telethon` as your question tags seem to indicate, it is recommend that you [read through the `asyncio` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html). In particular, threads and processes are trickier to deal with when using `async` libraries. `asyncio` is capable of running multiple tasks at the same time just as well.